# Camera access on the Mirage Solo?

Tags: android, google-vr, daydream, google-vr-sdk

The Lenovo Mirage Solo VR headset has a stereo camera system in the front which is used by the built-in Google WorldSense tracking system.

According to the [Google dev blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/09/new-experimental-features-for-daydream.html), support for AR/see-through might appear at some future point (or not, knowing Google).

However, since I'm interested in raw camera access anyway, I was wondering if anybody has already taken apart or rooted the Mirage Solo to see if the raw stereo camera data might be accessed?

Based on some digging with a device info app, it looks like the camera uses [OV9282](https://www.ovt.com/sensors/OV9282) sensors (monochrome, global shutter, 1 MP, up to 120 FPS), but that's all I was able to find out so far.

Any additional pointers would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I'd also be happy if someone could point me to a download link for the factory image files. I haven't been able to find those anywhere either.

Comment: FTR, there is an "open-source" download from Lenovo which contains the kernel source: https://smartsupport.lenovo.com/de/en/products/smart/arvr/mirage-solo/downloads/ds503129 - in theory, that should allow us to roll your own ROM image with root access, and take it from there. But this code dump is nowhere near complete, and the WorldSense component itself is apparently not open-source, so major hacking required.

Comment: The Mirage Solo received an update a few days ago which does enable the see-through mode for the safety graphics (so you don't walk into walls). And according to https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/988, there's a new SDK release planned for the next few days which should at least support texture pass-through.

Comment: Since the product is discontinued by Lenovo, and Google also seems to be loosing interest in the Daydream platform, I don't see much chances of this happening officially anymore. The best bet for this feature would be to create a custom ROM image AFAICT, but for that to work, we'd first need to root the device.